# Is there a way to back up my App Services / Usergrid data

Tags: apigee, usergrid

App Services is a great place to store data but now that I have a lot of critial info in there I realized there isn't a way to create a backup or roll back to an earlier state (in case I did something stupid like -X DELETE /users)

Any way to back up this data either online or offline?

Comment: Would be nice to know if you can do this and include user accounts / encrypted passwords too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from API access to fetch records x by x and storing locally, there is no solution at the moment. Team is planning an S3 integration (export data to S3) but no completion date is defined for that yet.

Comment: Problem with a scripted download (aside from speed when dealing with large collections) is that I have no way to back up my /users because I don't get their passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the only way is to query the data using e.g. CURL and save the results to a local file. I dont believe there is a way to export natively.

http://apigee.com/docs/app-services/content/working-queries

Comment: If [this is you](https://www.linkedin.com/in/ikqureshi), then you should disclose your affiliation in your user profile and probably also in your answers. Additionally, please don't post link only answers in case of link rot; post the full answer here and the link as a citation.

Answer (score 0):

From 2014/2015 Usergrid versions it is possible to make exports and imports using "Usergrid tools"
On this page it is explained how to install them :

https://github.com/apache/incubator-usergrid/tree/master/stack/tools

Basically once you run

```
$ java -jar usergrid-tools.jar export
```

and this will export your data as json files in an `export` directory.

There are several export and import tools avaible, the best way to see them is to visit this page :
https://github.com/apache/incubator-usergrid/tree/6d962b7fe1cd5b47896ca16c0d0b9a297df45a54/stack/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/usergrid/tools